# Content in nested tabs not displaying full 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I have nested tabs set up but the contents inside the second set of tabs (`#tab-2-1`, `#tab-2-2`, `#tab-2-3`) aren't stretching to their full 100% width. Is there something I missed?

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Bonus Episodes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Videos</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/44386375%3Fsecret_token%3Ds-bi246&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tab2-1">Foreally Stream</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2-2">Ross</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2-3">Jude</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab2-1" class="tab_content">
        [videogallery id="video-stream"]
    </div>
    <div id="tab2-2" class="tab_content">
        [videogallery id="ross"]
    </div>
    <div id="tab2-3" class="tab_content">
        [videogallery id="jude"]
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.tab_content { 
  background:#000;
  color:#fff;
  max-width:500px;
  padding:10px 
}
.tabs li { 
  display:inline;
  list-style:none 
}
.tabs a { 
  background:#7c7c7c;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  color:#dadada;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:10px 15px 8px;
  text-decoration:none 
}
.tabs a.active { 
  background:#e32d2d;
  color:#fff 
}
#tab2 ul.tabs a { 
  background:transparent;
  color:#999;
  padding:10px 10px 0 10px 
}
#tab2 ul.tabs a.active { 
  color:#fff 
}
```

JS

```
jQuery('ul.tabs').each(function(){
    // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
    // which tab is active and it's associated content
    var $active, $content, $links = jQuery(this).find('a');

    // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
    // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
    $active = jQuery($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
    $active.addClass('active');

    $content = $($active[0].hash);

    // Hide the remaining content
    $links.not($active).each(function () {
        jQuery(this.hash).hide();
    });

    // Bind the click event handler
    jQuery(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
        // Make the old tab inactive.
        $active.removeClass('active');
        $content.hide();

        // Update the variables with the new link and content
        $active = jQuery(this);
        $content = jQuery(this.hash);

        // Make the tab active.
        $active.addClass('active');
        $content.show();

        // Prevent the anchor's default click action
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see those showing up as tabs, did you include all the CSS?

Comment: To me they are showing up as 100% width but not as tabs..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rbt5gL6t/ - i have added this JS Fiddle and it seems to be working just fine..

Comment: @JDVangsness I included a live link for you guys in case it helps. I'm not sure why they're not showing up as tabs.

Comment: @EternalHour I included a live link for you.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS:

```
.videogallery .sliderMain {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

The `.videogallery .sliderMain` is being given an inline style with a width of 100px.

Whatever created the markup from the [videogallery] shortcode (WordPress plugin perhaps?) is giving it the 100px width. You can either override this in your CSS (with the above) or you can investigate further how it is calculating the 100px by digging through the JS/CSS for the videogallery plugin.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was just about to post this exact answer, then saw your answer. This should do it.

Comment: I put that in but it only made the video 100% width. The thumbnail navigation below is still stuck at 100px. I tried adding `.main-navigation { width:100% !important } but nothing changes. The funny thing is that when I activate the developer console (F12) and then close it, the width changes to 100%. Any idea?

Comment: The plugin and/or JS adding the 100px width to .sliderMain is also adding the 100px width to this and then calculating the width of the thumbs inside to be 40px so it will be fruitless to overcome it all with CSS. Best to look at the plugin to see how it's deriving this value. If you wanted my guess, it'll be because the JS creating the video gallery and carousel is running before the video it loaded in so the width of that div will be small

Comment: That sounds like a likely explanation. I've already reached out to the creator of the plugin so hopefully he gets back to me. The weird thing is that when I put the video gallery into a regular tab (not a nested tab), it works fine.